# remove flash object border

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash

I am embedding swf object into my html document, but its showing border on top and left of swf object, how to remove it?

Same result on all browsers. If i increase the dimensions of swf object then border start appearing on all sides. I dont want the border at all.

Comment: All browsers, one specific browser? What kind of border, dotted, solid? Nowhere close to sufficient information here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be wrong defined size for SWF object (width and height) which results in showing part of the swf's background. Try to change background color for object or it's size.